# Easy Pie Chart IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, charts

Is there an option of getting the pir chart: http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/ working in IE8? It is written that is goes, but can't get it to work.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.0.0 you'll find a demo for IE7 and 8. I tested it on my Windows VM and it worked.

You will need to add excanvas and the javascript polyfill for Function.bind in javascript.